# API call going in timeout from windows forms working fine from Postman

Tags: c#, winforms, api, timeout, postman

I am trying to call API from windows forms its going in timeout. but its working fine from POSTMAN app.

I am using below code for calling web API from windows app.

```
public string ReadXMLResponse(string strrequestxml, string strTallyServer1)
{
    string URL = strTallyServer1;

    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "application/xml";
    myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
    myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 60000;

    string method = "POST";
    myHttpWebRequest.Method = method;
    if (method == "POST")
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(strrequestxml);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }
    }

    HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var streamRead = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        return streamRead;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: This issue was more related to API not working properly and not giving response at all time. So issue is solved. It was tally API which was not giving output some time and sometime giving properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same code and the same problem. It was driving me crazy till I found something on one of Microsoft blogs. Tried to google the original page but I couldn't find it.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("URL");
request.Method = "POST";
var postData = string.Format(dataFormnat, Uri.EscapeDataString(data.Serialize()));

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```